# How to scheduling a report which will generate different report files based on all the values in an input control in JRS community version?

Tags: jasperserver

I am using Jasperserver Community version. I want to schedule to generate different report files for all the values of query based input control and also want to send the report to different email addresses.

For an example I have a report set up on Jasper Server that shows all the order details of a customer based on the parameter CustomerID. Now I want to schedule the report to be generated every month, for all customers. These CustomerID's are populated in a Multi-select query. How can I set up a schedule job that generates separate reports for all values of the input parameter?

If I am having 10 customers then 10 seperate reports will be generated and the corresponding report file will be emailed to that particular customer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate schedule for each customer. Each schedule then uses the parameters particular for that customer and the generated report is emailed only to them.

You cannot achieve what you want using only a single scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the feature that you ask for is not available in JasperServer as of version 6.2. The feature to create multiple outputs of the same report for a list of parameters is called "report bursting".

The proposed solutions by others are to user Talend, Jasper ETL or Pentaho to create a job and run it in some other scheduler.

As I am looking for a solution myself I plan to create a certain Java class, that can be somehow instantiated and get a method call from an empty Jasper report. The class will create a report for each parameter. Possibly the class can use some configuration from JasperServer.

The advantage of my solution is that it can be run from JasperServer ad-hoc! For example a user can just run the report and it will generate the set of reports behind the scene.

P.S. creating a separate schedule for each possible parameter is not a solution and writing it here is just waste of time and space